# What's wrong with my function when calculating the matrix mutiply?

Tags: arrays, c, function

So I have a pointer in my function but fail to pass the result of the matrix to the main function. Hope to get your help! Here's what I have got. I mainly wrote a programme to read a PGMB file and put it into a 2D array. Then do some transform to the array to it. And then do a matrix multiply with 2 matrix

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>



void Matrix(float matA,float matB, float *matC);
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char filename[100];
    float A[28][28];
    FILE *fp;
    printf("please input filenames: ");
    scanf("%s",filename);
    fp = fopen(filename,"rb");
    if(fp == NULL)
        printf("invalid file.\n");
    char skip[50],ch1;
    int i,j;
    fgets(skip,5,fp);
    while((ch1 = fgetc(fp)) != EOF){
        for(i = 0;i < 28;i++){
            for(j = 0;j < 28;j++)
                A[28][28] = ch1;
        }
    }
    for(i = 0;i <28;i++){
        for(j = 0;j < 28;j++)
            A[28][28] = A[28][2] / 255.0;
    }
    float B[784];
    int k = 0;
    for(i = 0;i < 28;i++){
        for(j = 0;j < 28;j++){
            B[k] = A[i][j];
            k++;
        }
    }
    FILE *W;
    W = fopen("W1.txt","rb");
    float C[784][128];
    char ch2;
    while((ch2 = fgetc(W)) != EOF){
        for(i = 0;i < 784;i++){
            for(j = 0;j < 128;j++)
                C[784][128] = ch2;          
        }
    }
    float D[128];
    D[128] = Matrix(B[784], C[784][128], D[128]);
    FILE *B1;
    B1 = fopen("B1.txt","r");
    char ch3;
    float E[128];
    while((ch3 = fgetc(B1)) != EOF){
        for(i = 0;i < 128;i++)
            E[128] = ch3;
    }
    float F[128];
    for(i = 0;i < 128;i++){
        F[i] = D[i] + E[i];
    }

}

void Matrix(float matA, float matB, float *matC)
{
    int count = 0,a,b,c,i,j;
    float sum = 0;
    double matA[a][b],matB[b][c],matC[a][c];
    while(count < a*c){
        for(i = 0;i < a;i++){
            for(j = 0;j < b;j++)
                matC[i][j] += matA[i][j] * matB[i][j]; 
        }
    }
}
```

So I have been stuck by the question for a long time. I am not sure if the 2D array can be input like my programme do.

Comment: Your compiler should be producing some very clear diagnostics (error and warning messages) for this program, even at a basic warning level. If not, you need a better compiler. If so, please edit the question to include the specific diagnostic you do not understand, and describe what you do not understand about it.

Comment: Your Matrix() takes 3 parameters, then attempts to create 3 different local variables with the same names. (Note also that local variables are destroyed at function exit, so returning them wouldn't work.) The interface to your Matrix function also doesn't match how you are trying to use it. Stop a moment and consider how you intend to use Matrix() and what its interface should be.

Comment: The for loop that does `A[28][28] = A[28][2] / 255.0;` repeatedly, and entirely independently, to the duo-loop control variables `i` and `j`, is nonsense. `A[28][28] = ...` - that array of arrays is only 28x28 elements wide, meaning with zero-based indexing, the allowable indexes are in 0...27. You're breaching your array limits. That assignment makes no sense whatsoever. `C[784][128] = ch2;` is similarly nonsense, as is `E[128] = ch3;`. Perhaps some more time in your C reference text is on the horizon.

Comment: Almost nothing about this makes sense to me. Are you trying to apply some sort of convolution to the image?

Comment: Additionally you use uninitialised variables (`a`, `b`, `c`) to produce your local `double` matrices (with equal names to the parameters as mentioned already), which is undefined behaviour. If you want to pass matrices in then you need to provide them as appropriate parameters like e.g. `void matrixMul(size_t a, size_t b, size_t c, double matA[a][b], double matB[b][c], double matC[a][c])`. Note that the outermost dimension is only for documentation and easier writing, but actually these are pointers of type `double (*matX)[Y]`.

Comment: Back to basics... If `fopen()` fails, STOP processing! An error message is good, but insufficient... In haste to "get it working", it's so easy to skip the safeguards, isn't it?

Comment: Algorithmically your matrix multiplication is not correct either, you need a tripple loop instead (if you are not willing to implement some high performance algorithm for large matrices like Strassen): `for(size_t i = 0; i < a; ++i) { for(size_t j = 0; j < c; ++j) { double sum = 0; for(size_t k = 0; k < b; ++k) { sum += matA[i][k] * matB[k][j]; } matC[i][j] = sum; } }`

Comment: Honestly, there's so much going wrong you shouldn't ask about what's wrong with the matrix multiplication, but with the entire programme – answer: nearly *anything*. To give you an image of how to do that basically here's a [minimal demonstration](https://godbolt.org/z/c3jTE9fM9) on godbolt.

Comment: You need to start with something much simpler than this.  You're trying to dive into the deep end of a pool before learning to swim, and as a result you're drowning.  You need to learn the basics of arrays, pointers, and function arguments at the very least.  Instead, you're trying to use two-dimensional arrays and pointers to arrays without understanding how they work.  Take a step back.  You're not ready for this.

Comment: At the very least, you should try to eliminate all compile-time warnings before posting your code.  If you don't understand a warning and can't eliminate it, then *that* should be the subject of a much narrower, more focused post.

Comment: [Commented version](https://godbolt.org/z/6eadvsMEP) of the example above...

Comment: Thank you for your help.  But actually, I just start to learn C and this is my group project, for some reason I need to try to do it on my own.

Comment: @EricACE The best advice a beginner can get is: **Fix all warnings before executing your program**. The `gcc` compiler has a very nice option for this, i.e. `-Werror`. It turns all warnings into errors which mean that no executable will be made before all warnings have been fixed. It's so nice... use it! For `gcc` you should always at least do `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror ....` and you will save a lot of time.